# how to get a list of all nodes that haven been created and are not in use on the system

Tags: nodes

as the title says.. 
i need to get a all published nodes of type A that have been created and not used (at the moment) by other nodes.

in other words a list of all node of type A that are on the Database except for those that are NOT been referenced in an entity reference field.

the easy approach will be to load all nodes that uses node of type A, and that load all type A nodes and check for each if it's has a reference for it.
but then if i add another node that will use node of type A as an entity reference i'll have to go back check it as well.

is there an easy way to do it ?

Comment: What does _in use on other nodes_ mean?

Comment: How do I in your case define that a node has been used by another? Is it that they are referenced in a entity reference field? That they are linked to from the text in the body field? Etc.

Comment: sorry, i meant referenced in a entity reference field.

Comment: Don't explain in comments, edit your question to clarify :)

Comment: When you say "Never been used", does that mean if a reference has existed, and then been removed, should that count as "Have been before and thus should not show up in the list"?
Does it have to be dynamic enough to search through _all_ possible entity references, or would one specific field suffice?

Comment: @Letharion i edited the question, i'm looking at the present state of the entity reference, but yes i do need it to be dynamic, because i can always add a new content type that will have an entity reference to this "type A" content type.

Comment: FWIW, dynamically finding fields of a certain type across all entities (or one particular entity type) is not trivial. Hopefully someone will know, but I wouldn't count on getting an answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a view showing title of content type A,  title of content type B (using relations), hide both and create a custom PHP field that just returns title of ct A if ct A does not have ct B referencing to it. Maybe